# Detecting an attribute being added to a video element and acting on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I need to listen for **controls="controls"** attribute being added to the **video** tag after content is loaded, i.e by a user manipulating the DOM.

The reason for this is because i have a custom set of controls, and do not want people adding the default controls value back in.

I have tried a few things:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vidplayer').live(function(){
        var attr = $(this).attr('controls');
        if(attr)
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('controls');
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vidplayer').change(function(){
        var attr = $(this).attr('controls');
        if(attr)
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('controls');
        }
    });
});
```

I have done quite a bit of research on event listening but I am struggling to get my head around it, I'm hoping someone here has the knowledge to help!

The ID For the video tag is **#vidplayer**

Other than that, if someone knows of a way of disabling controls all together, or disabling the full screen mode then that is **as** useful!

Hopefully I've explained myself fully.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if the "people" remove the event listener as well? :/

Comment: This is a good point, I think people are less likely to pursue a task if they are stopped at the first hurdle. So I'd very much like to put that first hurdle in, I thought about an interval to check every xseconds for the attribute but i am not sure this is ideal!

Comment: I wouldn’t want any script to enforce such magic behaviors to my DOM, would you? A node is what it is, as soon as someone appends it to their document they can and will do whatever they want with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to resort to a polling mechanism (setInterval with periodical checks), 
you'd have to use [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) (DOMAttrModified) which are deprecated because they killed browser performance or [Mutation Observers](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) that aren't implemented yet in most browsers.

I can't test it here, because my browser (chrome) has not implemented them yet. But the thing should work like this:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('videoelement');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    $(target).removeAttr('controls');
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData:   false }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Ah thankyou for this, I guess the browser performance is why they havent implemented this properly. Thanks for your answer, i think this is the closet i am going to get to what i need.